iLogic Rule Not Executing in APS Environment
I'm using an iLogic rule embedded in an assembly file to update parameters, open linked drawings, and export PDFs for use in Design Automation. However, the rule doesn't seem to be running correctly, and no output is being generated or sent back to the bucket.
I followed all the recommended steps for creating an APS-compatible iLogic rule, including adding logs for each action and trying to export a log.txt file. Despite these efforts, the log.txt file isn't being created when I run the workItem. It seems like the iLogic rule might not be executing at all.
Here is the error report:
[11/15/2024 18:15:32] Job information:
{
  "CommandLine": [
    "$(engine.path)\\InventorCoreConsole.exe /i \"$(args[inputFile].path)\" \"$(args[InventorParams].path)\" /s \"$(settings[script].value)\" "
  ],
  "Settings": {
    "script": {
      "value": "iLogicVb.RunRule(\"MyRule\")"
    },
    "dasOpenNetwork": {
      "value": "true",
      "isEnvironmentVariable": true
    }
  },
  "Id": "c073a813e1584614b5b75968a321424d",
  "ActivityId": "y9RzOGD5tXcdhKNJpxpsSMsyqhNT4DnYSbAjOsli5hD7mt81.drawingautomation17+dev",
  "EngineId": "Autodesk.Inventor_2025!44",
  "Apps": [],
  "BoundArguments": {
    "inputFile": {
      "zip": true,
      "localName": "input",
      "pathInZip": "630AF.iam",
      "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:X4NXLXxOZ3IZVhJalhri7cVVyMg=",
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Masked:LgiH6MHsvmMxrQRQh667CaFUblc="
      },
      "verb": "get"
    },
    "InventorParams": {
      "localName": "input\\params.json",
      "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:jrcCsOry8tUPWxWaatYh0JInitA=",
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Masked:LgiH6MHsvmMxrQRQh667CaFUblc="
      },
      "verb": "get"
    },
    "outputFile": {
      "localName": "input\\630AF.pdf",
      "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:QN/HWF0qHe+7jvWfMfNeYvxKghA=",
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Masked:LgiH6MHsvmMxrQRQh667CaFUblc="
      },
      "verb": "put"
    }
  },
  "Quotas": {
    "limitProcessingTimeSec": 900,
    "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 500
  }
}
[11/15/2024 18:15:32] Starting work item c073a813e1584614b5b75968a321424d
[11/15/2024 18:15:32] Start download phase.
[11/15/2024 18:15:32] Start downloading input: verb - 'Get', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/jcbucket1/objects/630AF.zip'
[11/15/2024 18:15:32] Start downloading input: verb - 'Get', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/jcbucket1/objects/params.json'
[11/15/2024 18:15:32] End downloading file. Source=https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/jcbucket1/objects/params.json,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\c073a813e1584614b5b75968a321424d\input\params.json,BytesDownloaded=39,Duration=111ms
[11/15/2024 18:15:32] End downloading file. Source=https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/jcbucket1/objects/630AF.zip,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\c073a813e1584614b5b75968a321424d\zip_27.zip,BytesDownloaded=7342731,Duration=266ms
[11/15/2024 18:15:32] T:\Aces\Jobs\c073a813e1584614b5b75968a321424d\zip_27.zip has been unpacked to folder T:\Aces\Jobs\c073a813e1584614b5b75968a321424d\input.
[11/15/2024 18:15:32] End download phase successfully.
[11/15/2024 18:15:32] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[11/15/2024 18:15:32] Command line: [ /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\c073a813e1584614b5b75968a321424d\input\630AF.iam" "T:\Aces\Jobs\c073a813e1584614b5b75968a321424d\input\params.json" /s "iLogicVb.RunRule("MyRule")" ]
[11/15/2024 18:15:32] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[11/15/2024 18:15:33] Start script phase.
[11/15/2024 18:15:33] Start Inventor Core Engine standard output dump.
[11/15/2024 18:15:33] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : InventorCoreConsole.exe: 25.0.18300.0, 3-27f3b8a
[11/15/2024 18:15:33] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Starting Inventor Server.
[11/15/2024 18:15:33] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Trying to get Inventor Server version in use.
[11/15/2024 18:15:33] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Inventor Server version is 29.0.16200.0000.
[11/15/2024 18:15:33] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Inventor Server version is 2023 or newer
[11/15/2024 18:15:33] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Started Inventor Server 2025 (Build 290162000, 162) (29.0.16200.0000)
[11/15/2024 18:15:33] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Loading plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[11/15/2024 18:15:33] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Activating plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[11/15/2024 18:15:33] iLogic Plugin: initializing...
[11/15/2024 18:15:33] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Loading plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[11/15/2024 18:15:33] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting up iLogicLogLevelTo: Warn
[11/15/2024 18:15:33] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Opening document: T:\Aces\Jobs\c073a813e1584614b5b75968a321424d\input\630AF.iam Invisible mode: False
[11/15/2024 18:15:36] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Opened
[11/15/2024 18:15:36] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Loading plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[11/15/2024 18:15:36] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Performing iLogic diagnostics...
[11/15/2024 18:15:36] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : End of iLogic diagnostics...
[11/15/2024 18:15:36] CoreConsole Dispose start
[11/15/2024 18:15:36] CoreConsole ReleaseAll start
[11/15/2024 18:15:36] CoreConsole ReleaseAll end
[11/15/2024 18:15:36] CoreConsole Dispose end
[11/15/2024 18:15:36] CoreConsole exiting (0)
[11/15/2024 18:15:38] End Inventor Core Engine standard output dump.
[11/15/2024 18:15:38] End script phase.
[11/15/2024 18:15:38] Start upload phase.
[11/15/2024 18:15:38] Error: Non-optional output [input\630AF.pdf] is missing.
[11/15/2024 18:15:38] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase Publishing of job.
[11/15/2024 18:15:38] Job finished with result FailedMissingOutput
[11/15/2024 18:15:38] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedInstructions"
}


It's possible that the rule is running but the file you generate does not end up in the subfolder named "input" of the working folder. Add /iLogicVerbosity Trace to the commandLine to see more logs.
You can also use adskDebug to zip the whole working folder and see what files were created and where: 
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/using-argument-adskdebug-troubleshot-failure-job-design-automation
A colleague just noticed that you are not using path for the script /s \"$(settings[script].path)\" 
(there will be a file generated from the script content that you can load into Inventor, that's why it's path and not value) 
Please follow this: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/run-ilogic-rule-without-appbundle

The iLogic now works beautifully, but another issue shows up, I am able to get the PDFs sent back but the model isn't updated at all. I checked the logs it says the parameters are updated, not so sure why the model isn't. Any clue?

I'm pretty sure the model is updated, but the dwg linked to it is not. Not sure what's happening up there.

"I'm pretty sure the model is updated" - you can use the adskDebug option I mentioned before to get back the full working folder content of thew work item and then you can see what the state of the various documents are
